# Problem - Sum of digits of $n$ and its square

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

How can I solve this problem : 
$z(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$. So $z(15) = 1+5 = 6$

For all natural number $m$, there's an integer $n$ such that : $z(n)*m = z(n^2)$ ? 
You can find these integers here : https://oeis.org/A224792
Note : $n > 0$

Comment: The link is definitely not unrelated. The link gives the smallest $n$'s such that $z(n)\cdot m=z(n^2)$ for $m=1,2,\cdots$

Comment: $n$ is an integer $> 0$, and like the OEIS link is saying we have for $m = 4$, $n = 13$ because : $z(13)\cdot 4 = z(169)$ and so on and so forth

Comment: No, it doesn't give the smallest.  For example, $A224792(8) = 1011113$, but $211113$ is smaller and $z(211113) \cdot 8 = z(211113^2)$.

Comment: I think, there are some mistakes in the OEIS sequences but nevertheless it gives integers $n$ that satisfy the properties

Comment: Why do you think there are mistakes in this sequence?  It does give integers that satisfy the property.

Comment: Because as you just said it doesn't give the smallest integer $n$ that satisfy the property, whereas the title is saying : "Smallest skinny number"

Comment: Look at the definition of skinny number in A061909.  Numbers satisfying your property don't have to be skinny.  In particular, $211113$ is not skinny.

Comment: Ok, my bad but nevertheless the problem is still unsolved, any ideas to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Prove by induction: for any positive integer $m$ there is a number $n$ with all digits $0$ and $1$, $z(n)=m$ and $z(n^2) = m^2$.

For the induction step, note that if $n$ works for $m$, then $10^k + n$ works for $m+1$ if $k$ is sufficiently large.